# Create new page based on table length

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with two sheets. Sheet A containing a formatted report and Sheet B containing raw data.

On Sheet B there is a table which can 1 to n rows. This table is also shown on a page on Sheet A (derived).

How can I autmatically create a new page on Sheet A, if the table in Sheet B contains more rows than the table in Sheet A can hold?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you're doing this but something like this might work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     dim ws as worksheet
     dim tbl as listobject
     dim MaxRows as integer

     set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("SheetB") 'Change with worksheet name
     set tbl = ws.listobjects(1)
     MaxRows = 22 'Number of Max Rows in table

     if tbl.listrows.count > MaxRows
         ' Add code to add new 'page on Sheet A'
     end if
End Sub
```

This will Run on any change within SheetB (place this code in the worksheet module) Then count the number of entries in the table on Sheet B before running whatever code if it has exceeded the maximum number.